# Different project on Wordpress sub directory

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to develope a project on a sub directory of my web root where WordPress is installed. Somehow it keeps showing 404 error page. Let me explain -

http://www.mysite.com - [Web root directory/WordPress site installed]

*.htaccess of this directory:*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

http://www.mysite.com/crm/ - [New directory 'crm' where I stored my CodeIgniter project/Secured pages]

*.htaccess of this crm directory: (this is for Codeigniter project)*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Whenever I try to access the second link, it shows 404 error. Please help me to solve this issue.

** If I use normal html file, it works, but for secured page, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `/crm/.htaccess` as:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /crm/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` as this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^crm(/|$) - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I need 15 rep for +1 you, haha sorry :)

Comment: Hey np at all you have already accepted it. I upvoted your question to give you 5 reps :)

Comment: bro, now WordPress pages are not working. All of them return 404 page error. Please check - http://akijceramics.net/ and http://akijceramics.net/akijcrm/ , I did not check the site last night. Please help.

Comment: For temporary solution, I set permalink mode to default, but when i set it to www.site_name/page_name format, it shows 404 error page.

Comment: My rule above doesn't impact WP rules. If you notice I am just shipping a single directory crm from WP handling. Did you change crm to your actual directory name?

Comment: I just copy paste your code except changed 'crm' to 'akijcrm'. Nothing else.

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile since I am Traveling. So will be just commenting. Are you noticing that /akijcrm is going to WP?

Comment: Are you noticing that requests for `/akijcrm` are going to WP?

Comment: /akijcrm is okay now, but other directories are not okay. I had to use ?page_id=# permalink type for teamporary solution. Any solution?

Comment: Which directories are not okay? My rule only creates exception for `/akijcrm` other directories remain unaffected.