# Can't access sub directory on server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I had a server with wordpress installed on its root(it's already live). Now i have created a new directory on root and want to install another wordpress on that.When i tried to access that sub directory its showing page not found error.

```
My .htaccess file is as follows

# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions

<IfModule rewrite_module>

 RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1

RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]

</IfModule>

# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

tried the following but didn't work

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/english/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

sub directory name is english.

Can anyone help!!!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have an htaccess file in your subdirectory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different project on Wordpress sub directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773761/different-project-on-wordpress-sub-directory)

Comment: @JonLin no i don't have .htaccess file on that sub directory

Comment: If you remove the new block you mentioned above and create a test page file in english folder, does this work?

Comment: @LucasF created one index.html and index.php page,i can access the html page but can't access the php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work if you have this rule in htdocs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
    # END s2Member GZIP exclusions

    # BEGIN WordPress
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

And this in english subfolder:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /english/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, tried the above code but didn't work.Its still showing page not found error.

Comment: Hmm...in my environment it's working. Are there any other rules? Maybe in httpd.conf?

Comment: Can you please create another php script in /english and try to access it

Comment: Its working...,i have created another folder and placed your code in it.I had wordpress files inside /english folder may be because of that didn't work.

Comment: Maybe also browser caching... Will you accept my answer then?