# exclude folder in wordpress using htaccess failed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a folder named folder1 after entering the root. At that level of directory there's my .htaccess, I googled and I paste the following line at

```
..
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
// this
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
..
```

But when I go to mydomain.com/folder1, it returned 404 of my wordpress?

Comment: This may help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529123/cant-access-sub-directory-on-server

Answer (score 0):

You should post all of your code so that we can make sure there aren't other rules conflicting. Not just the part you can't get working.

Try using THE_REQUEST and try it this way and put it above your wordpress rules. So if it matches then do nothing.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST) /(folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. Did you try to clear your cache? or in another browser.

Comment: it's not cache problem. I visited mydomain.com/folder1, is that the correct way?

Comment: It still returned my wordpress 404 page.

Comment: Something else is wrong. Because the wordpress conditions already are made so that it won't rewrite real folders with this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and adding another condition to make sure it doesn't rewrite does work. Are you sure everything is working in the htaccess?

Comment: I have no idea what's going on too, above code is what is exactly what is  within my .htaccess

Comment: Make sure your /htaccess is being read properly. put some rand garbage at the top of the file. It should create a 500 internal error. Then you should know if it's reading it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, exclude **subfolder** with **wordpress** **.htaccess** and workds for me.
I put this before **WordPress** rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yoursubdirectoryname1/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is **WordPress** rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My complete .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/yoursubdirectoryname1/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . //index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

source: I found this code on [WordPress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sub-directory-from-exclusion-of-redirectrewrite-htaccess-tweak#post-6578202).